# Two amps running through a transistor?

Tags: transistors, amperage

(Short disclaimer, I don't know much about electrical engineering other than what I have learned in physics in high school and the little I have learned from working with electrical engineers)

Is it common to have 2 amps running through a transistor (than can support it of course) or is there some sort of circuit design or something that would allow you to direct the current to where it needs to go and have a lesser current run through the transistor while still having the transistor in use?

I feel like 2 amps running through a single transistor is bad (idk if it is or not) so I just wanted to see if there was another way to do it... also save me money so I don't have to buy more expensive transistors

Comment: A transistor rated for 2 Amp drain current (or collector current if NPN) can conduct less than rated current, if that's what you're asking? How much current actually flows, depends on the complete circuit. The various circuit elements influence each other.

Comment: @MarkU I know it can draw less, I just wasn't sure if it is common practice to have a transistor draw 2 amps. I'm not electrical engineer so I wasn't sure if it is a good or bad idea.

Comment: There is no such beast as "common practice," so avoid using terminology like that around engineers and scientists. ;-) Transistors do exist that can carry two amps of direct current, while other transistors would be damaged/destroyed by two amps of direct current. You must always refer to the transistor's (i.e., the component's) data sheet to determine its maximum ratings.

Comment: If you know you need to switch a current of 2 A max then I'd select a transistor that is rated for at least 3 A or so. But current rating isn't the only constraint. Learning about using transistors is not about asking yes/no questions. It is about gaining an understanding of what a transistor does and looking at examples how experienced engineers use a transistor. On this site there are already too many "I know nothing but is this OK ?" questions.

Comment: You can get transistors (IGBTs) that can handle [more than 1000A](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-FZ1200R33KL2C-DS-v02_03-en_de.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b4319ab354c0)  and ones that will be damaged by [less than 10 mA](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BFT25A.pdf). You need to find a part that can handle the maximum current when on (including surges) and the maximum voltage when off (include surges) with margin to spare, and hopefully both available/cheap/fast/easy.  Suggest you try to solve your real problem and ask another question that includes your proposed load etc.

Comment: I would put it this way: in circuits which control 2 amp currents, it is indeed common practice to do so with a single transistor. But. As has been pointed out, you need to select a transistor which will handle 2 amps gracefully. Many won't. You also need to select appropriate drive circuitry, and also consider both voltage and power limits. But in general, 2 amps through a single transistor is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've practically got all your answers in the comments above. But you also brought up cost. So I thought I'd add a few points and try and wrap it up.

Transistors commonly have to handle more than 2A. They may do this for purposes roughly like a switch (turning something ON, like a solenoid) or for purposes not at all like a switch (like the speaker driver stage of an audio amplifier.) But because transistors also drop at least some voltage across them when doing this work, they also have to dissipate power, too, while achieving their primary purpose.

So, in any design you need to also keep in mind power dissipation. There are transistors designed for *small signals* which are generally these days packaged into tiny TO-92 packages or SOT-23-X packages. These are not designed to dissipate much power into ambient air. So you usually have to stay under a quarter watt or so with those. Less is still better. The temp at the surface of the package means that the temp inside the package is still that much higher. So you need to make sure that the actual bit of silicon deep inside doesn't exceed its ratings. The 2 amp number you give pretty much takes it out of this ball-park of small signal devices.

However, there are packages that fit squarely into that area of current. These are TO-220 packages. And for many 2A applications, they may be just fine. Again, everything is in the particulars. There are "safe operating areas" and you may have to drop large voltages across the transistor, so you still have to think and read datasheets to make sure. But as a broad rule, the TO-220 package (and similar) probably will handle many 2A situations.

There are two basic kinds of transistors: FETs and BJTs. They each have their place, still. So which of them will be better will, again, depend on circumstances. Since you mention cost, I'd say as a broad rule BJTs are cheaper than MOSFETs. I can get BJTs for less than a penny each (I buy PN2222A at about 0.4 cents each.) I can't do that anywhere with any MOSFET, such as a 2N7002, which all have a base that is much higher. However, that's not all there is. They each require drive circuitry and that also costs money as well as having different trade-offs in performance.

But a TO-220 packaged BJT can often be found for well under 40 cents. (Assuming you get it shipped for free, I guess.) They really aren't that expensive. And I'm pretty sure similar MOSFETs aren't much different in pricing, when talking about TO-220 packages.

So it's not the big deal you suggest there. Handling 2A isn't that bad and isn't that expensive, in many applications. (Of course, for some it would be prohibitively expensive. So no bright lines here, either.) In fact, it's considered pretty normal.

Answer (score 1):

The question you should ask is not about current, but about *power dissipation* in the transistor. The power dissipated in the transistor is equal to the current (Ic) times the voltage between emitter and collector (Uce). So the power dissipated in the transistor is I<sub>c</sub> * U<sub>ce</sub>.

It is this power that heats up the transistor, and you are responsible for transporting that heat away (into a heatsink) before the transistor breaks.

There are 3 cases:

1. the transistor is closed. The current is zero, so no power is dissipated.
2. the transistor is fully open. Now the current is maximal, but the Uce is low, so the power dissipated in the transistor is moderate.
3. the transistor is not fully opened. Now the current may be intermediate, but Uce is not low. Somewhere within this case the transistor dissipates maximum power.

So you need to make sure the transistor is driven 'hard' enough to make sure it is sufficiently 'on', and does not get into regime c.

To check this you need to know the ratio between the collector current and the base current, called the *DC current gain* or *h<sub>FE</sub>*. For a transistor that can handle a few amps this ratio may be as low as 40. This means that the base of the transistor needs about 2A/40 = 100mA of drive current. You should check if you driver can supply that.

When in doubt, look for a [darlington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) version of your transistor (which has much higher h<sub>FE</sub>.)

Answer (score 0):

> is there some sort of circuit design or something that would allow you to direct the current to where it needs to go and have a lesser current run through the transistor

This circuit would normally involve routing the current through another, bigger, transistor.

In the end, the most common way of switching the paths currents take through a circuit is to route them through a transistor.

Of course, you could also use a relay (but this would generally require more power from the controlling circuit), or a mechanical switch (but that would require operator intervention to change the switch state).